# Как при инициализации не добавлять класс к input а только после submit во Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Хочу сделать валидацию инпута, что при нажатии на submit только тогда добавляеться класс is-invalid или is-valid но проблема с моим кодом что класс is-invalid уже висит при инициализации формы, как можно сделать чтобы после клика? http://joxi.ru/8AnaM6PizNdqp2

```
   <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-bind:class="[status.title ? 'is-valid' : 'is-invalid']" placeholder="Title" v-model="article.title">
            <div v-if="errors.title" class="invalid-feedback">{{errors.title}}</div>
        </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        data() {
            return {
              article: {
                id: '',
                title: '',
                body: ''
              },
              errors: {title: ""},
              status: {title: false}
            }
          },
        methods: {
          handleSubmit() {
                        if (!this.article.title) {
                            this.errors.title = 'Title required';
                            this.status.title = false;
                        } else if (this.article.title.length < 5) {
                            this.errors.title = 'Title must contain at least 5 characters';
                            this.status.title = false;
                        } else {
                            this.errors.title = '';
                            this.status.title = true;
                        }
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два направления.

В первом вы в data вводите данные заранее валидные.
Вам это не очень подходит, т.к. длина поля title должна быть более 5ти и придётся заставлять пользователя стирать данные.

Во втором подходе вы тупо вводите новую переменную "надо валидировать" и меняете условие на

```
<div v-if="need_validate && errors.title"
```

Также в `<form @submit` вам надо будет вызывать установку этой переменной и опционально добавить "если проверки не прошли - отказаться от сабмита формы".

```
   <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-bind:class="[status.title ? 'is-valid' : 'is-invalid']" placeholder="Title" v-model="article.title">
            <div v-if="need_validate && errors.title" class="invalid-feedback">{{errors.title}}</div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
    <script>
            data() {
                return {
                  article: {
                    id: '',
                    title: '',
                    body: ''
                  },
                  need_validate: false,
                  errors: {title: ""},
                  status: {title: false}
                }
              },
            methods: {
              handleSubmit() {
                            need_validate = true;
                            if (!this.article.title) {
                                this.errors.title = 'Title required';
                                this.status.title = false;
                            } else if (this.article.title.length < 5) {
                                this.errors.title = 'Title must contain at least 5 characters';
                                this.status.title = false;
                            } else {
                                this.errors.title = '';
                                this.status.title = true;
                            }
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста показать на моём примере, я не совсем понимаю как правильно сделать